# Who (and when) first defined interval graphs?

Tags: graphs, reference-request, history

I've been searching google scholar for references and narrowed down the first mention to somewhere around [1963](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interval%20graph&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=) with a very weird jitter in 1949.

So, I'm trying to track down the original paper introducing interval graphs for citation, but it's been rather elusive so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to track the first occurences of interval graphs down to

**G. Hajos, [Über eine Art von Graphen](http://www.oemg.ac.at/IMN/imn047-48-teil2.pdf), Int. Math. Nachr. 11 (1957) page 65**

This reference refers to a book of (talk) abstracts. In the abstract of Hajos  interval graphs are defined, without actually calling them *interval graphs*. Moreover it says, that he gives conditions whether a graph is a interval graph and he discusses how to reconstruct the intervals defining the graph, when the graph fulfills these conditions.

Comment: How did you track down the paper and verify it's originality (regarding interval graphs)?

Comment: I found many interval graph papers citing this source. See for example the paper of [Fulkerson and Gross](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183526254)

Comment: I actually managed to [find it](http://www.oemg.ac.at/IMN/imn047-48-teil2.pdf) (page 34 ---65---), and it does describe what we call interval graphs, but it's a mere abstract. I don't know if you can read German, but it basically states the problem of determining if a given graph is an interval graph. It appears to be genuine, but I'd have loved an actual paper instead of an abstract advertising a talk. Do you think such a paper even exists?

Comment: @bitmask: Thanks for the link, I included it in the post. Also, since German is my mother tongue, I have read the abstract and included a short summary.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I asked our librarian to try and dig up the full paper. I'll see what comes from this.

Answer (score 2):

According to Golumbic [1], Hajös proposed the following problem in 1957 (translation by Golumbic):

> Given a finite number of intervals on a straight line, a graph associated with this set of intervals can be constructed in the following manner: each interval corresponds to a vertex of the graph, and two vertices are connected by an edge if and only if the corresponding intervals overlap at least partially. The question is whether a given graph is isomorphic to one of the graphs just characterized (Hajös [1957, p. 65, translated by M.C.G.]).

Golumbic also discusses how interval graphs were related to a question in biology made by Benzer [2] in 1959.

---

[1] Golumbic, Martin Charles. Algorithmic graph theory and perfect graphs. Vol. 57. Elsevier, 2004.

[2] Benzer, Seymour. "On the topology of the genetic fine structure." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America 45.11 (1959): 1607.